# ESRI iOS SDK application size

Tags: ios, arcgis-ios, arcgis-runtime-sdk-ios

I'm developing a simple app with ESRI iOS SDK. I set up esri-sdk for iOS with CocoaPods, but CocoaPods installs all frameworks in project. In Xcode theestimated project size is about 250 MB.

I'm curious when I run ipa file, how many megabytes the ipa file will be on the device and then how can I decrease app size?